# Get a portion of a long field in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe that has some fields that contain very verbose text. I want to be able to iterate through the DF but only display a limited set of words. I have code similar to:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows() :
    print(row['A'], row['B'])
```

How can I make sure that I only print the first 300 characters from 'A'?

Comment: for index, row in df.iterrows() :
    print(row['A'][:300], row['B'])

Comment: See also https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#extracting-substrings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fairly simply, for 'A' only:

```
max_chars = 300
for index, row in df.iterrows() :
    print(row['A'][:max_chars], row['B'])
```